# Undefined Index When Parsing Base64 string using AJAX POST/GET method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to upload an image from my cordova application to my server (PHP will receive the base64 data decode and save it) But I'm encountering an error in POSTING namely undefined index from PHP side and I couldn't figure out what is causing the error. I tried assigning the base64 string in the PHP I am still getting an error stating that it is undefined.

I've tried to use $_GET in my PHP file but it still doesn't work

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera
var a;
var app = {
    image: null,
    imgOptions:null,


    initialize: function() {
      // Use deviceready on a device in in the emulator
           //     document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
      // Use DOMContentLoaded in a browser
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", app.callCamera);
        console.log("button listener added");
        app.image = document.querySelector("#image");
        document.querySelector('#testtestx').addEventListener("click",app.UploadtoServer);
    },


    callCamera: function () {
        app.imgOptions = {quality : 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                targetWidth : 200,
                cameraDirection : Camera.Direction.FRONT,
                saveToPhotoAlbum : false
               };

        navigator.camera.getPicture( app.imgSuccess, app.imgFail, app.imgOptions );
    },
    //OnSuccess Function
    imgSuccess: function (imageData) {
         a = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
         localStorage.setItem('base64imgimg',a);
        //got an image back from the camera
        app.image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        //console.log("Image loaded into interface");
        //clear memory in app
        navigator.camera.cleanup();
    },


    //OnFail Function
    imgFail: function (msg) {
        console.log("Failed to get image: " +  msg);
    },


    UploadtoServer: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'MYSERVERURLREPLACEDDUETOSENSITIVEITY';
        var killmeplease = localStorage.getItem('base64imgimg');
        console.log(killmeplease);
        var JSONObject = {
            "image": killmeplease,
            "name": 'test'
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSONObject, //Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.
            dataType: 'json', //Evaluates the response as JSON and return a JS object
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) { //function to be called if the request succeeds //this function will be called
              console.log('d');
            },
        });



    }
};

app.initialize();
```

And here's my PHP code

```
<?php


 //$currentdir = (dirname(__FILE__));
 $image = $_POST['image'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];


class image{

private $save_path = 'sdc/images/';
private $image_string = '';
private $image_name = '';
private $image;
private $response = array();

public $loaded = false;

public function __construct(){
    $this->response = array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'unknown error.'
    );
    $this->image_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $this->image_string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'image');
    if(!empty($this->image_name) && !empty($this->image_string)){
        $this->loaded = true;
    }
}
```

My base 64 string.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: You should post the actual error message. You should also read the docs for [`filter_input()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) regarding the third parameter, namely: "If omitted, FILTER_DEFAULT will be used, which is equivalent to FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. This will result in no filtering taking place by default."

Comment: @Sammitch the error from my console states that the variable is undefined but using AJAX post method, I have parsed the necessary data to it.

Comment: You should edit a quote of `the actual error message` into your post. `I have parsed the necessary data to it` (should that be `passed`?) What `it`? `the variable`? Which?!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. You're not making a form or multipart encoded POST, you're just stuffing raw JSON into the POST body. PHP won't decode that and therefore won't populate `$_POST` with anything.

The raw POST body will be available in the special stream [`php://input`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and you can snag and decode it like so:

```
$rawPost = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decodedPost = json_decode($rawPost);
$image = $decodedPost->image;
```

If you want to have PHP handle the request parsing natively you're going to want to figure out how to make your JavaScript make a proper `multipart/form-data` POST instead. As a bonus, you can just upload the image as-is without base64ing it, which saves you 25% on your request size and PHP will write it to a tempfile instead of memory.

Comment: I realised that my Ajax function the contentType was declared as 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. However, if I removed the contentType it will be reverted back to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and all almighty the data managed to parsed properly.